# Tcl package require loads the wrong package version?

Tags: package, tcl, version

I'm trying to deploy a beta version of a package and want existing code to run the stable release.

The built-in package versioning in Tcl 8.5/8.6 should work for that purpose. But I ran into the following very odd behavior, where the order in which pkgIndex.tcl files are loaded will affect which package is eventually loaded. I can get an unstable package to load even when "package prefer" is "stable".

I have tried this in multiple Tcl releases, 8.5 as well as 8.6, and in different Tcl enabled tools. All behave similarly.

This following code works as I expect:

```
% package prefer
stable

% package ifneeded p 1.1 {package provide p 1.1}
% package ifneeded p 1.2 {package provide p 1.2}
% package ifneeded p 1.3 {package provide p 1.3}
% package ifneeded p 1.4a1 {package provide p 1.4a1}
% package versions p
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4a1
% package require p
1.3
```

But when the "package ifneeded" statements are run in a different order, the unstable version is loaded:

```
% package forget p
% package prefer
stable

% package ifneeded p 1.4a1 {package provide p 1.4a1}
% package ifneeded p 1.3 {package provide p 1.3}
% package ifneeded p 1.2 {package provide p 1.2}
% package ifneeded p 1.1 {package provide p 1.1}
% package versions p
1.4a1 1.3 1.2 1.1
% package require p
1.4a1
```

What is the explanation for this behavior? Can I prevent it, or do I simply have to be very careful when I append library paths to auto_path?

Comment: This is a bug. Ticket opened. https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview/5d6de65036f6ecd229c8c46e591aae520547968a

Comment: This is a bug. Ticket opened: https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview/5d6de65036f6ecd229c8c46e591aae520547968a